How do I get an EmbeddingStore with langchain4j using
How do I get an EmbeddingStore instance connecting to milvus using a tls certificate?
Normally I just use
EmbeddingStore<TextSegment> embeddingStore = MilvusEmbeddingStore.builder()
.uri("http://localhost")
.collectionName("tryLoadAgainHere")
.build();

But the MilvusEmbeddingStore() don't have any support for taking a ssl/tls certificate.
I did manage to get a working instance of MilvusServiceClient which connected to the database, but i don't know how to use that to get a MilvusEmbeddingStore.
I looked at the soure code to MilvusEmbeddingStore (https://github.com/langchain4j/langchain4j/blob/main/langchain4j-milvus/src/main/java/dev/langchain4j/store/embedding/milvus/MilvusEmbeddingStore.java#L369) but it looks like MilvusEmbeddingStore create its own instance of MilvusServiceClient and there is no way to pass in an existing connection.
